# Can't remove Emoji-Picker package

Tags: gnome, package-management, software-center, deb

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 Gnome 42, and I've recently installed with the Gnome Software an app called Emoji-Picker, but now I can't uninstall it with the Gnome Software because for some reason it can't remove DEB packages – the error message I get is

```
Unable to remove "Emoji Picker": no packages to remove`
```

and using the terminal I got the same message

```
E: Unable to locate package emoji-picker.
```

Does anyone know how I can remove it, and also know why the Gnome Software isn't removing any DEB packages? Thanks very much.

Comment: You sure you have the right package name? It appears as if the package has a different name than you expect. Are you able to run the program by simply typing `emoji-picker` in the command line? Also try: `apt list --installed | grep "emoji-picker"` and see what comes up.

Comment: I am able to run the program typing `emoji-picker`, but when I run `apt list --installed | grep "emoji-picker"` It says `WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.`